# Python Qt5. Using loops to call the QPushButtons

Tags: python, loops, qt5, qpushbutton

I'm a junior QT user. Trying to understand how it works.
I have multiple QPushButtons. They were created in a QT Designer.

```
    self.K2o = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.K2o.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
    self.K2o.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 58);")
    self.K2o.setCheckable(True)
    self.K2o.setObjectName("K2o")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.K2o, 14, 1, 1, 1)
    self.A3o = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.A3o.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
    self.A3o.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 58);")
    self.A3o.setCheckable(True)
    self.A3o.setObjectName("A3o")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.A3o, 13, 0, 1, 1)
    self.b33 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.b33.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
    self.b33.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(122, 184, 255);")
    self.b33.setCheckable(True)
    self.b33.setObjectName("b33")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.b33, 13, 12, 1, 1)
```

[Main window with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaejE.png)

They are all checkable.Sometimes I need to make the same actions with different buttons. How I can use a loop in this situation.
For example I want to change "check status" for my buttons on the next not using this one:

```
    self.AA.setChecked(False)
    self.KK.setChecked(False)
    self.QQ.setChecked(False)
    self.JJ.setChecked(False)
    self.TT.setChecked(False)
    self.b99.setChecked(False)
    self.b88.setChecked(False)
    self.b77.setChecked(False)
    self.b66.setChecked(False)
    self.b55.setChecked(False)
    self.b44.setChecked(False)
    self.b33.setChecked(False)
    self.b22.setChecked(False)
```

The main question is how a can call the button using its text or objectName maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer... :)

My buttons are all in GridLayout. So I just need to find all children of it widget.

```
self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
for button in self.gridLayoutWidget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
    if button.isChecked():
        button.nextCheckState()
```